# На каком языке пишут код для ардуино?

Tags: c++, c, arduino

Решил узнать на чём пишется код для ардуино, гугл говорит что на С\С++. Но я не пойму, на котором из них? Или может быть на обоих?

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/

Comment: Всё-равно не понятно

Comment: Можно писать на чём угодно, в том числе на C++17 и на чистом C при желании. Arduino programming language схож с древним C++ с дополнениями

Comment: C++, только не Modern =)

Answer (score 3):

В Arduino IDE можно писать на любом из них.

*Теоретически можно писать вообще на любом компилируемом языке, был бы компилятор под платформу.*

Answer (score 3):

Ардуиновский "рантайм", если можно так выразиться, написан на урезанном C++. Собственно, я бы советовал писать скетчи на C++, а в случае необходимости "спускаться" до ассемблера. По-факту же, вы можете использовать практически любой язык. Например, есть возможность "зашить" в Arduino движок [Espruino](https://www.espruino.com/) и писать на JavaScript. Если интересно как это сделать, то можете почитать статью [Espruino: JavaScript в микроконтроллере](https://habr.com/ru/company/amperka/blog/392399/). Но учтите, что использование интерпретируемых языков добавляет много накладных расходов, что не всегда приемлемо.

Спасибо @insolor за уточнение:

> Espruino не заработает на Arduino, только на более мощных контроллерах - например на STM32 (упоминаемые по второй ссылке Espruino Board, Espruino Pico, Iskra JS реализованы на контроллерах семейства STM32), ESP8266, ESP32

Comment: Espruino не заработает на Arduino, только на более мощных контроллерах - например на STM32 (упоминаемые по второй ссылке Espruino Board, Espruino Pico, Iskra JS реализованы на контроллерах семейства STM32), ESP8266, ESP32

Comment: @insolor есть IskraJS от амперки на ARM Cortex-M4. Но, по-большому счету, разницы нет какая железяка - суть везде одна будет.

Comment: См. https://amperka.ru/product/iskra-js : `Микроконтроллер: STM32F405RG (32-битный ARM Cortex M4)`

Comment: `Но, по-большому счету, разницы нет какая железяка - суть везде одна будет.` - разница есть. В Espruino реализован интерпретатор, запускающийся на контроллере, и не каждый контроллер такое потянет (по производительности и по ресурсам в целом). Теоретически конечно все можно реализовать, но фактически под чипы используемые в классических Arduino (ATmega328, ATmega32U4, ATmega2560) тупо нет прошивки Espruino: https://www.espruino.com/Other+Boards . Для компилируемых языков другое дело - главное чтобы был кросс-компилятор.

Comment: @insolor я имел ввиду, что принципы будут одинаковые. :)

Answer (score 2):

Вот тут обсуждают, как разговаривать с Ардуино из питона: https://realpython.com/arduino-python/

Вкратце, вместо обычной загрузки кода на плату предлагается, чтобы на компе крутился код на питоне, который будет разговаривать с Ардуино, забирая оттуда сигналы и подавая команды при помощи скетча `Firmata` и модуля`pyfirmata`.